# Print data about people with age limit from text file in C

Tags: c, file, structure

My task is to make a program which reads a .txt file and shows in console information of people who are older than 60 in one case and lets me find a person by their surname in the second case. The text file contains information of their position in list, birth date, country, name, surname. The first works, but I am having a hard time getting a result in second case.

```c
 int Search_in_File(char *fname, char *str) {
        FILE *fp;
        int line_num = 1;
        int find_result = 0;
        char temp[40];

        if((fp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
            return(-1);
        }

        while(fgets(temp, 40, fp) != NULL) {
            if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {
                printf("\n%s\n", temp);
                find_result++;
            }
            line_num++;
        }

        if(find_result == 0) {
            printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
        }

        //Close the file if still open.
        if(fp) {
            fclose(fp);
        }
        return(0);
    }
```

```c
getchar();
switch(sel){
case 1:
                printf("Find person\n");
                printf("Enter surname to find: ");
                fgets(cmp, 40, stdin);
                err = Search_in_File(fname, cmp);
                if(err < 0)
                {
                    return err;
                }
                break;
case 2: //here should be the option of printing people who are older than 60
       }while(sel!=4);

    return 0;         
}
```

What would be the correct and best way to do this? Considering I have to calculate the age without the leap year or atleast just the years itself(without months and days).
For example if I have 4 people:

```
1 11/10/1987 country1 John Doe 
2 12/08/1950 country2 Mary Solley 
3 23/02/1988 country3 Kieth Owell 
4 29/12/1954 country4 Bob Stevens
```

And I choose the option to display people who are older than 60 it should output:

```
2 12/08/1950 country2 Mary Solley 
4 29/12/1954 country4 Bob Stevens
```

Comment: Are you allowed to have memory objects instead of reading from the file all the time? Usually one would just have a `struct` that undergoes [un-]serialisation to store it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
char line[] = "4 11/10/1987 country1 John Doe";
```

you can extract the day, month, and year, as strings, with

```
char day[3] = "";
char month[3] = "";
char year[5] = "";
strncpy(day, line+2, 2);
strncpy(month, line+5, 2);
strncpy(year, line+8, 4);
```

Beware the ID. When it gets to 10 (or 100, or 1000), you need to adjust the starting indexes.